# The difference between context and scope

Tags: java, scope, cdi

Studying JSR-299, I read section 5.1 of the [Weld reference](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/pdf/weld-reference.pdf) which explains how scopes work in CDI. Apparently, context is a concept closely related to scope. The difference is not clear in my mind and I feel tempted to even use the words interchangeably.

What is the difference between scope and context? What is the relationship between the two concepts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each scope has a separate context.

The context is a container for beans which have been defined with the respective scope.

That's why context implementations carry the name of the scope - `ApplicationContext`, `DependentContext`, `RequestContext`, etc.

This is an implementation detail actually - as a user of CDI you should only know about scopes (because you define it for your beans), and the implementation decides where to place those beans and how to manage their lifecycle.

Comment: Good point. Let me add that in Seam 2 **context** was the concept that the user was well aware of (`@In`, `@Out`), while in CDI **scope** is the way to go. This certainly is a changed of the perspective.

Comment: Where can I read more about these Context classes (Javadoc or other documentation)?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that scope refers to where an object may be accessed from, while context enumerates the objects that can be accessed from some particular point in program execution. (That is, we talk about the scope of an object, and the context at some particular point in program execution.)

Mathematically speaking, both describe the can-access relation, but look at it in different directions.

Comment: probably more accurate to say the scope of a *variable*

Comment: While I agree with that in general, that would be misleading when talking about CDI, since CDI really defines scopes for objects, not variables. (In CDI, an object runs out of scope (and is hence destroyed) completely independent of any variables pointing to it).

Comment: not `variable` in Java's sense, but in general sense. if two sessions can share one object, it's not proper to talk about *the* session scope of the *object*.

Comment: Well, if two sessions can share an object, there is no sense in talking about the session scope of the object because it not session-scoped anyway, no?

Answer (score 1):

First, we have concepts in our heads like applications, sessions, requests. Let's use the session concept in the following examples.

If we consider that a piece of execution is serving for a particular session, we'll say the session is part of the context of the execution; or, it is *the* session context of the execution.

A session has some variables, e.g. `userName`; we'll say the session is the scope of these variables.

Since both are pointing to the same session, it can get confusing. For example,

```
get the userName from the session context
get the userName from the session scope
```

both sound fine, because we are talking about an execution on a variable.

The following example is intelligible per the definition of scope

```
the scope of the injected bean is Session
```

but we don't have problem understanding what's really going on. If we want to, we can expand it till it's based on basic usages of words; we don't do that because it will be very verbose.

An author faces the difficult task of packing the words succinctly yet expecting readers somehow understand the complex meaning. Texts about context and scope usually appear to be gibberish to those who haven't understood the concepts.

API names are even more difficult to come up with, because codes are not English sentences. `Context` or `Scope` are pretty much interchangeable. If there's only one object representing a session, the class probably should be named just `Session`. If we split the part about variable manipulation, that part can be called `SessionScope`. However, the meaning of `SessionContext` is too elusive, the best we can tell, from the name alone, is that it is about something of a session - "context" here is pretty much an expletive.

Comment: My problem is exactly to explain what are contexts and scopes in an article. Both your explanation and the meriton's one makes sense to me and seems to talk about more or less the same thing, although I've found his explanation more aligned to what I "feel". My hope was to get some standard, broadly adopted definitions but apparently I will have to choose my own definition, unfortunately...